# Cannot run VM in VMWare on Windows 10 due to Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have successfully installed VMWare Workstation 10 on my laptop running Windows 10. The virtualized system is CentOS.

#### Could install guest system and run it

I could successfully install the system and all, but after upgrading to Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I get this:

[image]

#### Removed Hyper-V

I have uninstalled everything from the system concerning Hyper-V. I removed it from my computer and restarted several times. No luck.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue. Removing and disabling Hyper-V did not help.
Turns out the problem was related to Device Guard (I have Windows 10 Enterprise). I found the answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4fdb9c2a-8437-4fe2-b48a-dbc3d65cce9e/build-14295-vmware-workstation-pro-12-thinks-hyperv-is-installed?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview). But the gist of it is:

1. Download the [Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337)
2. Run the tool in powershell with the correct execution policy):

   ```txt
   DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.2.ps1 -disable
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Make sure you have Hyper-V uninstalled and disabled:

   ```txt
   Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```

Comment: The downvote seems undeserved. This indeed solves the problem on Windows 10 Enterprise, and is otherwise a very hard to find solution. You should stick around during the reboot, though, as Windows will ask you to confirm you want to opt out.

Comment: For step 4 I get `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'All'.`

Comment: There is a extra space in the last command. it should be  Microsoft-Hyper-V–All

Comment: For step 4 command must be: `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`

Comment: The only thing that worked after trying so many other things. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me. Success after trying many other approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 should have an option in the boot configuration data which determines whether Hyper-V starts during Windows startup (there is in Windows 8.1). So to disable Hyper-V from starting, in an administrator command prompt you type: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and reboot the computer. After that you can run VMs in Workstation.

To turn Hyper-V back on again, type in an administrator command prompt: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and reboot the computer. ([Source](http://www.ivobeerens.nl/2013/12/16/running-hyper-v-and-vmware-workstation-on-windows-8-x/))

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is just disabling Device Guard. Below I show you how to disable it:

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. Go to *Computer Configuration* → *Administrative Templates* → *System* → *Device Guard*. On the right side double click to edit the properties of "Turn On Virtualization Based Security". Set the setting to "Disabled".
3. Open cmd as administrator and type the below commands:

   ```
   mountvol X: /s
   copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
   bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:
   mountvol X: /d
   ```

After doing this you have to reboot and approve the changes with F3.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9zqbo0/running_both_hyperv_and_vmware_workstation/:

> Hyper-v is a type 1 hypervisor, vmware is type 2. They cannot coexist
>   (on any OS).
>
> However, you can create a second boot entry so you can boot in hyper-v
>   mode or vmware mode.
>
> https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx

```
C:\>bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V" 
The entry was successfully copied to {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea}. 

C:\>bcdedit /set {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea} hypervisorlaunchtype off 
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: This is what does (and has) always worked for me.  I use a BCD boot option to switch between hypervisor on or off.

Answer (score 0):

The presented **DG_Readiness_Tool** woks well unless you are in corporate environment where the uninstalled Device Guard may be **reinstalled by central policy**.

To overcome that I did [this:](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339)

**gpedit.msc** -> set Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security to *Disabled*

Comment: This is a good point. However, in most corporate cases, this group policy will also be forced by the company i.e. overwritten with the next GP update.
Therefore, chances are rather low that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Good news！ the Vmware Workstation 20h1 preview version  has supported Hyper-V,you can download it here:
https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/01/vmware-workstation-tech-preview-20h1.html

Answer (score 0):

**install the latest vmware workstation > 15.5.5 version**

which has the support of Hyper-V Host

**i also installed VMware.Workstation.Pro.16.1.0 version**

and it fixed my issue now i am using the docker and VMware same time
even my window Hyper-V mode enabled

Answer (score -1):

1. download the ADK.exe
2. After downloading it , press WIN + F and search for
   Compatibility Administrator(64 bit).
3. After opening the Compatibility Administrator(64 bit), expand System Database(64bit)
4. Now Expand the Applications and search for VMware Workstation Pro.
5. After getting it click on the VMware Workstation Pro and in the right
   there would be two components.
       a> vmplayer.exe
       b> vmware.exe
6. right click on the both option independently and choose Disable Entry option on both the components .
7. after clicking that you will get the red colour  at both components.
8. after that go and open VMware .

Comment: These instructions suck.. even if they might work.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. It comes with the anniversary update of Win10. This update add an extra security functionality but hyperV stuff is necessary to activate this function.
Here is the kb to workaround the problem :
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361
It works for me.
Mika (from France, so be cool with my poor english !!)