# Trying to build a VMWare Workstation lab, I have a Azure instance of Windows Server 2016 Datacenter,

Tags: windows, vmware, hyper-v, azure

Here is the scenario.

I am planning to build a VMWare lab on Azure. I have spun off a VM on an MS Azure VM with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Installed VMWare Workstation player 15 version. Downloaded the Windows server 2012 ISO. When I try to boot the machine to the disk, I am getting the following error.

> Windows Server 2016 Datacenter does not have the Hyper-V role enabled.

Please check the image below

[image: Please click here for the image]

Comment: DeviceGuard?  [VMWare Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible](https://superuser.com/questions/1286791/vmware-workstation-and-hyper-v-are-not-compatible)

Comment: Your Azure VM is a VM running on a modified Hyper-V stack.  The only way to due nesting would be with Hyper-V in your VM.  The CPU features that VMware needs aren't translated through.

Comment: So as I understand, I need to enable Hyper-V on my server, then install virtual machines, hope my I reading it correctly? Please let me know.