# Running VMWare Workstation Player on Azure VM

Tags: vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, azure

So, there are a lot of questions on this but I did not manage to find a concrete answer. I have an OVA file representing a server which as far as I know, I can only use VMWare to open this file and access the copy of the server. Due to lack of physical space on my personal device, I decided to create an Azure Virtual Machine and install VMWare over there to be able to access the copy of the server.

The Azure Virtual Machine is Windows Server 2019. I installed VMWare Workstation 16 Player on this machine. I am getting the error: "VMWare Player and Hyper-V are no compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMWare Player."

[Screenshot here, since I cannot embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coxhD.png)

On a separate thread ([Trying to build a VMWare Workstation lab, I have a Azure instance of Windows Server 2016 Datacenter,](https://superuser.com/questions/1514066/trying-to-build-a-vmware-workstation-lab-i-have-a-azure-instance-of-windows-ser)) one user has stated that "the Azure VM is running on a modified Hyper-V stack", and according to this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9zqbo0/running_both_hyperv_and_vmware_workstation/eab87xe?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> Hyper-v is a type 1 hypervisor, vmware is type 2. They cannot coexist (on any OS).

I tried various suggestions to overcome this as suggested by other user in other threads:
[Cannot run VM in VMWare on Windows 10 due to Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/1115702/cannot-run-vm-in-vmware-on-windows-10-due-to-hyper-v) ;
[VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible](https://superuser.com/questions/1286791/vmware-workstation-and-hyper-v-are-not-compatible) ;
[VMware workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. How to Remove the Hyper-V role?](https://superuser.com/questions/1290666/vmware-workstation-and-hyper-v-are-not-compatible-how-to-remove-the-hyper-v-rol) .

I tried downloading the tool here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337 . I also tried various bcdedit commands in the command line. But nothing seems to work unfortunately.

Furthermore, I know about "Azure VMWare Solution", but the pricing of it makes it unfeasible.

So, my questions here are:

- Is it at all possible to run VMWare Player on an Azure Virtual Machine?
- If yes, than what shall I do to achieve this?
- If not, than what alternative options do I have to run VMWare not locally, either on the Azure platform (preferably) or using a different service?

Comment: Assuming "physical space on my personal device" means "available hard drive space", VMWare machines will run reasonably well when stored on a fast USB or other external drive. You won't want to use this kind of rig for gaming, but for software dev/testing and such, it works quite well.  And as a Just FYI, I once got the bright idea of storing VMs on SD cards; figured it'd save on weight bigtime. Weight savings, that worked out nicely. Boot time ... I guess it would have booted up by now if I'd left it running.  Sloooowwwwww. Bad idea.

Comment: VMware is a company. VMware Player will not run in an Azure VM, but will run in a local Hyper-V VM with the necessary configuration made on the local host and VM settings.  You, as a user of Azure, do not have that level of access to an Azure host. Why do you need to run a nested VM?  Your Azure VM, well, is already a VM, just use that.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg , thanks for the advice. Didn't think of running it on an external drive, so it is something I will definitely try.