# VMWare Workstation not working despite Hyper-V is off

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, amd-ryzen

I know that Hyper-V and VMWare Workstation is not compatible so I never turn that feature on. Yesterday I ran VMWare with no problem. But today, an error occurs saying that my Hyper-V is on
This is what it's look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdQqd.png

Here is the full Windows Feature:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY2ZZ.png

Virtualization is enabled says the task manager:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtveY.png

**UPDATE**

I always turn on The Windows Hypervisor Platform and never did anything to the VM. But turns out, turning it off solve the problem

Comment: Please read this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286) and submit a screenshot of the information from the Intel tool.  Edit your question to include the required information necessary to answer your question.  Please do not reply to this comment.

Comment: Please read my extensive linked answer and provide the information from that tool.  If you are being notified Hyper-V is enabled then it actually is.  I suspect you have enable Windows Sandbox, but your screenshot is incomplete, and only partially lists the installed Windows features

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run VM in VMWare on Windows 10 due to Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/1115702/cannot-run-vm-in-vmware-on-windows-10-due-to-hyper-v)

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the Windows Hypervisor Platform solve the problem though it was always turned on before the problem. Sorry for the trouble