# VMWare Workstation 16 conflicting with Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 10 Pro hosting Hyper-V, which has a VM (Windows 10 Enterprise). The VM has VMWare Workstation 16 installed, and I am trying to open an existing VM from a previous Windows 10 laptop.

I get the following error message:

[image]

I have followed the same answer steps within [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1115702/cannot-run-vm-in-vmware-on-windows-10-due-to-hyper-v), but I still get the same message followed by another message, even after multiple reboots.

What I have done more importantly:

- Disabled virtual based security
- Amended the reg keys (and imported what was advised)
- Hyper-V is disabled, along with Virtual Platform and Virtualization features

Does something need to be configured within the Hyper-V settings for the Win10 Enterprise VM?

Comment: What is your Windows version? VMware Workstation can now run with Hyper-V starting with Windows 10 20H1 build 19041.264 ([link](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html)).

Comment: You need the newest version of Windows to go with the new version of VMware.

Comment: The Win10 Ent VM is version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.867). The VMware Workstation installed on it is version 16.1.1 build-17801498. So if they are both compatiple, that error message should not exist in terms of version perpective?

Comment: Uninstall VMware Workstation, restart the computer and install Workstation again. Also try a new test Guest system.

Comment: Wait you are running VMWARE Workstation within a VM?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am, And the VM is run by Hyper-V. Any issues with this setup?

Comment: Nested Virtualization is at least not enabled by default AFAIK.

Comment: Where would I need to enable nested Virtualization ?

Comment: It’s well documented by Microsoft

Comment: Unfortunetaly they only show explain nested Virtualization when using Hyper-V and within a Hyper-V. I am trying to enable VMWare within a Hyper-V host